# Otto. Avoid @Produce validation warnimg message

Tags: android, android-annotations, otto

Android Otto library gives below warning message when `@Produce` method is used. How to avoid the message?

```
Note: Validating elements
C:\Users\Me\GroupViewActivity_.java:90: warning: Element ProduceHandler unvalidated by 
public GroupViewEvent produceGroup() {
                      ^
C:\Users\Me\GroupInfoFragment_.java:111: warning: Element SubscribeHandler unvalidated by 
public void onUpdateGroup(final GroupViewEvent event) {
```

I use otto in order to communicate between Fragment and Activity. The activity (in above, GroupViewActivity.java) has `@Produce` method and child Fragment has `@Subscribe` so that it receives updates.

In addition, I'm using Otto+AndroidAnnotation with following guide: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/OttoIntegration

Comment: I am afraid that wiki article is outdated. AA now works with the stable version of Otto, please use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WonderCsabo mentioned, it works great in current release of AndroidAnnotations(v3.2) and otto(v1.3.6). Do not have to use `otto-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` version.